# Printing with no new line with inherited classes

Tags: python

Just learning python and I write simple code along the way.
Overriding the print method in the derived class, can I print both classes in the same line, without changing the base class?
i.e. I want `pointA.print()` to print
"`x = 10 and y = 10 and z = 10`"; not `x = 10 and y = 10 and z = 10`

I know in C# this can be done easily as the `WriteLine` method starts with a new line (as opposed to ending with it), and so, the *Write* method does what I expected it to.

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def print(self):
        print(f"x = {self.x} and y = {self.y}")


class PointWithZAxis(Point):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        Point.__init__(self, x, y)
        self.z = z

    def print(self):
        Point.print(self)
        print(f"and z = {self.z}")


pointA = PointWithZAxis(10, 10, 10)
pointA.print()
```

Comment: `print(..., end="")`, because the default is adding a line break in the end (`end="\n"`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the print in the parent class to this:

```py
print(f"x = {self.x} and y = {self.y}", end = "")
```

BTW, it is cleaner in my opinion to overwrite the `__str__` method of the classes than to make a `print()` method. The `__str__` method of an object is automatically called when you print the object (like: print(object)). The code then becomes:

```py
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return f"x = {self.x} and y = {self.y}"


class PointWithZAxis(Point):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        Point.__init__(self, x, y)
        self.z = z

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + f"and z = {self.z}"


pointA = PointWithZAxis(10, 10, 10)
print(pointA)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add end="" to print

```
print("something", end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `end` argument to the print function lets you specify the ending of you `print` statement, so:

```
print(..., end='')
```

By default it is set to `end='\n'`, which indicates a new line.

P.S. be careful with naming funcions `print` as they shadow already existing functions and may cause confusion.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple other people who are responding with `print(..., end="")`. This is a quick-fix, sure. But there's something else I'd like to point out.

Since you're a beginner, I'd say you've encountered a good example that teaches why you should think a little about the kind of APIs/interfaces you're designing. Take a step back and ask yourself this question: "Who are the consumers (callers) of `def print(self)`? And what do they want." The point here is, you can have different callers each wanting a different thing. These problems arise when you're not able to find the common denominator across all that they want. Introducing parameters to the function is one way. In other words: your derived class can send in a additional parameter asking to not append a newline,  while those that call from outside of `PointWithZAxis.print(..)` need not know about this parameter.

---

Here's an average solution:

```
class Point:
    ....
    def print(self, include_newline=True):
        print(..., end=("\n" if include_newline else ""))

class PointWithZAxis:
    def print(self):
        Point.print(self, include_newline=False)
        print(....)
```

---

Here's a good solution (Don't print. How about making the job just to construct a string? Actual printing can be the callers job).

```
class Point:
    ....
    def get_print_string(self):
        return f"x = {self.x} and y = {self.y}"

class PointWithZAxis:
    def get_print_string(self):
        return super().get_print_string() + f" and z = {self.z}"

# You can then do:
p = PointWithZAxis()
print(p.get_print_string())
```

---

**Pythonic solution (recommended)**: Use `__str__(..)`. This is the recommended way of doing what `get_print_string()` does.This function indirectly gets called when you do `print(AnyClass())`. Refer to @Bram Dekker's solution.